# How can I execute an ant task more than once?

Tags: ant, build-automation

Imagine this as the code from build.xml:

```
<project name="test project">
    <target name="first">
        <echo>first</echo>
    </target>
    <target name="second" depends="first">
        <echo>second</echo>
    </target>
    <target name="third" depends="first,second">
        <echo>third</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

What do I need to do so that when I run:

```
ant third
```

I would receive the following output:

```
first,first,second,third
```

In other words, I would like each dependency to run regardless of whether it has ran before or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not what dependencies are for.

If you need that behavior, use [`antcall`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) or [`MacroDef`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) instead.

```
<project name="test project">
    <target name="first">
        <echo>first</echo>
    </target>
    <target name="second">
        <antcall target="first" />
        <echo>second</echo>
    </target>
    <target name="third">
        <antcall target="first" />
        <antcall target="second" />
        <echo>third</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

---

```
> ant third
Buildfile: build.xml

third:

first:
     [echo] first

second:

first:
     [echo] first
     [echo] second
     [echo] third

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```